# Always "Sending Data" In MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I'm running this query, but in processlist this state is "Sending Data", i try with Maria DB 10 this query running successfully, but in MySQL 5.6.44 always sending data,
can you help me to solve this problem

Table/View v_stock

| PartName | Qty Stock |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |

tbl_cummulative

| id | cummulativeQty | qtyOrder | qtyStore | partName | mscode | fob | refreshDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 15 | 20 | A | AA | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| A | 0 | 5 | 20 | A | AA | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-01 |
| A | -5 | 5 | 20 | A | AA | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-01 |
| A | -10 | 5 | 20 | A | AA | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-01 |

```
select s.partName AS partName,
group_concat(distinct c.mscode separator ',') AS model,
(select min(cum.fob) from dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative cum where cum.partName = s.partName and cum.cummulativeQty < 0) AS fob,
s.qtyStock AS qtyStock,
sum(c.qtyOrder) AS qtyOrder,
min(c.cummulativeQty) AS qtyShortage,
(
    select min(dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative.cummulativeQty) AS cummulativeQty 
    from dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative 
    where dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative.fob = (select min(cum.fob) from dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative cum where cum.partName = s.partName and cum.cummulativeQty < 0) 
    and dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative.partName = s.partName and dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative.cummulativeQty < 0
) AS qtyOrderClosest 
from (dbbomv2.v_stock s 
left join 
dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative c on(s.partName = c.partName)) 
group by s.partName 
order by c.fob is null,c.fob,s.partName
```

i need table like this

| partName | model | fob | qtyStock | qtyOrder | qtyShortage | fobqtyOrderClosest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | AA | 2021-01-03 | 20 | 5 | -5 | 2021-01-03 |

This MySQL 5.6.44
[image: MySQL 5.6.44]

This Maria DB 10
[image]

Comment: check the myxsql   it will show if the buffers are too small

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to analyze the optimization plan for the query in both servers. Look for a difference in the index chosen, and the number of rows examined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve, i remove this query and running this query at program

```
(
    select min(dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative.cummulativeQty) AS cummulativeQty 
    from dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative 
    where dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative.fob = (select min(cum.fob) from dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative cum where cum.partName = s.partName and cum.cummulativeQty < 0) 
    and dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative.partName = s.partName and dbbomv2.tbl_cummulative.cummulativeQty < 0
) AS qtyOrderClosest
```